# Mongo select object where child element match

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i have this mongo structure :

```
   my_object {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5630c996b707fd090c060f21"),
    "local" : "FR-fr",
    "ARTD" : [
        {
            "id" : 0,
            "mot" : "le",
            "v_path" : ""
        },
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "mot" : "la",
            "v_path" : ""
        }
    ],
    "ARTG" : [
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "mot" : "ce",
            "v_path" : ""
        }
    ],
    "SUSU" : [ ],
    "RECS" : [ ],
    "SUBS" : [ ],
    "VT" : [ ],
    "PREP" : [ ]
}
```

I want to retrieve an object by id,
ex : if a give id 0, i want :

```
{
        "id" : 0,
        "mot" : "le",
        "v_path" : ""
}
```

if a give id 2, i want :

```
{
        "id" : 2,
        "mot" : "ce",
        "v_path" : ""
}
```

So, i want to find wheresoever is the object (under ARTD or ARTG...etc)

what command i can use for this in mongo shell ?

Sincerely,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the **[`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or)** operator for the query and the **[`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch)** to project the specific array element. Iterate the cursor from the **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** method using **[`forEach()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach)** to access the resulting documents, check the fields and access the matching field's array element. The following demonstrates this for the `id` 1:

```
var id = 1,
    query = {
        "$or": [
            { "ARTD.id": id },
            { "ARTG.id": id }
        ]
    },
    projection = {
        "ARTD": {
            "$elemMatch": { "id": id }
        },
        "ARTG": {
            "$elemMatch": { "id": id }
        }
    };
db.collection.find(query, projection).forEach(function (doc){
    var result = {}, key; 
    ["ARTD", "ARTG"].forEach(function(key) {
        if (doc.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            result = doc[key][0];
        }
    });
    printjson(result);
})
```

**Sample Output:**

```
{ "id" : 1, "mot" : "la", "v_path" : "" }
```